# Combine Camembert & CRF for token classification

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, crf

I want to combine Camembert and CRF in order to perform named entity recognition on French medical data.
I am following this [code](https://github.com/shushanxingzhe/transformers_ner/blob/main/models.py) combining Bert and CRF, but I can't reproduce the same thing with Camembert as I didn't find a `PreTrainedCamembert` class to pass and use instead of the `BertPreTrainedModel` used in the shared code.
I have tried to use the `CamembertModel` but it gave me a model in which the camembert layers are duplicated as shown below.

```
BertCRF(
  (embeddings): RobertaEmbeddings(
    (word_embeddings): Embedding(32005, 768, padding_idx=1)
    (position_embeddings): Embedding(514, 768, padding_idx=1)
    (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(1, 768)
    (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  )
  (encoder): RobertaEncoder(
    (layer): ModuleList(
      (0): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (1): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (2): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (3): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (4): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (5): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (6): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (7): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (8): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (9): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (10): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (11): RobertaLayer(
        (attention): RobertaAttention(
          (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
            (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
          (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
        )
        (output): RobertaOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (pooler): RobertaPooler(
    (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
    (activation): Tanh()
  )
  (cmbert): CamembertModel(
    (embeddings): RobertaEmbeddings(
      (word_embeddings): Embedding(32005, 768, padding_idx=1)
      (position_embeddings): Embedding(514, 768, padding_idx=1)
      (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(1, 768)
      (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    )
    (encoder): RobertaEncoder(
      (layer): ModuleList(
        (0): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (1): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (2): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (3): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (4): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (5): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (6): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (7): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (8): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (9): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (10): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (11): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  (classifier): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=21, bias=True)
  (crf): CRF(num_tags=21)
)
```

Any clues on how to fix this issue? I want to get a model similar to the BERT & CRF one.

```
BertCRF(
  (bert): BertPreTrainedModel()
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  (classifier): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=21, bias=True)
  (crf): CRF(num_tags=21)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore `BertPreTrainedModel` and initialize it as torch module:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

from torchcrf import CRF
from transformers import CamembertModel, CamembertTokenizerFast

class CamemBERTCRF(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_labels):
    super(CamemBERTCRF, self).__init__()
    
    self.encoder = CamembertModel.from_pretrained("camembert-base")
    
    self.config = self.encoder.config
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(self.config.hidden_dropout_prob)
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.config.hidden_size, num_labels)
    self.crf = CRF(num_tags=num_labels, batch_first=True)

  def forward(
      self,
      input_ids=None,
      attention_mask=None,
      token_type_ids=None,
      position_ids=None,
      head_mask=None,
      inputs_embeds=None,
      labels=None,
      output_attentions=None,
      output_hidden_states=None,
  ):
      r"""
      labels (:obj:`torch.LongTensor` of shape :obj:`(batch_size, sequence_length)`, `optional`):
          Labels for computing the token classification loss. Indices should be in ``[0, ..., config.num_labels -
          1]``.
      """
      outputs = self.encoder(
          input_ids,
          attention_mask=attention_mask,
          token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
          position_ids=position_ids,
          head_mask=head_mask,
          inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
          output_attentions=output_attentions,
          output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
      )

      sequence_output = outputs.last_hidden_state
      sequence_output = self.dropout(sequence_output)
      logits = self.classifier(sequence_output)

      loss = None
      if labels is not None:
          log_likelihood, tags = self.crf(logits, labels), self.crf.decode(logits)
          loss = 0 - log_likelihood
      else:
          tags = self.crf.decode(logits)
      tags = torch.Tensor(tags)

      output = (tags,) + outputs[2:]
      return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output


m = CamemBERTCRF(4)
t = CamembertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("camembert-base")

print(m(**t("this is a test", return_tensors="pt"), labels=torch.tensor([[1,2,3,2,3,1]])))
print(m(**t("this is a test", return_tensors="pt")))
```

Output:

```
(tensor(8.0685, grad_fn=<RsubBackward1>), tensor([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]]))
(tensor([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]]),)
```